# Is there a way to test a solidity smart contract funtions

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, binance-smart-chain

a bit of a noob question. I'm looking to test a solidity smart contract function without waiting 6 days. It's a feature implemented that will allow me to interact with the contract and be paid X amount only after 6 days. How can test that? TIA

Answer (score 0):

well it really depends on your tool set, if you are using hardhat you can write a test, that way you can easily know if that function work as intended, here to see [hardhat testing](https://hardhat.org/guides/waffle-testing.html) and here to simulate the pass of the [time](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#hardhat-mine) you only need to know how many blocks are mined in that time to use it

Comment: Thanks man, I have a dev working on a contract like this and I've been told we need to wait a couple of days to test that feature which is hard to believe that you can't sandbox the contract. I'll have a look over what you've sent me to wrap my head around what it needs to be done.

Comment: maybe is using a different tool that do not have that option, other option is to make that in a fork of the network where the contract is deployed